# Scala classes serving as containers of types - member types of singleton types as type parameters

Tags: scala, generics, path-dependent-type

Quick question: why the following doesn't compile:

```
trait SubtypeOf[+T] {
    type Type <: T
}

def SubtypeOf[T] :SubtypeOf[T] = new SubtypeOf[T] { type Type = T }

case class Owned[+P<:Owner](next :Option[P#R])

class Owner {
    type This = this.type
    val R = SubtypeOf[Owned[This]]
    type R = R.Type

    def next(o :Owned[This]) :Option[R] = o.next
}
```

result:

```
Error:(23, 43) type mismatch;
found   : Option[_2.R.Type forSome { val _2: Owner.this.This }]
(which expands to)  Option[_2.R.Type forSome { val _2: Owner.this.type }]
required: Option[Owner.this.R]
(which expands to)  Option[Owner.this.R.Type]
    def next(o :Owned[This]) :Option[R] = o.next
```

This is of course the most simplified recipe for the error I could come up with, and the motivation behind it and the long question follows:

I am implementing a protocol given as json schema consisting of a couple of dozen of classes nested under each other. Although this protocol is a standard, different partners implement their own extensions, and the number of of those partners grows. Lets say that the standard specifies a 'person' object which can be implemented as follows:

```
case class Person(firstName :String, familyName :String)
```

A typical extension would be similar to something like this:

```
class PersonP1(firstName :String, familyName :String, val birthDay :Date)
```

The problem begins to show if 'person' objects occur multiple times in embeded in various other objects in the data tree, for example : root.history.transactions.buyer, root.history.transactions.buyer.spouse, root.company.technicalContact, root.company.businessContact, etc. - you get the idea. In such a situation two simle solutions are:

1. Subclass only classes containing actually extended data - person, and pepper all code using it with casts. This is made even worse by the fact that actual business logic implicitly requires some objects to be of specific subclasses, which is impossible to enforce and a hell to document.
2. Subclass recursively all classes with references to extended entities, i.e all objects on the path to the root. This in practice requires subclasses most/a very large portion of the whole schema, often only by narrowing the type of one of the property.
3. Visitor pattern, which is slightly better than 1) but still doesn't allow declaring the whole data to be specific to one one partner.

I opted for solution 4:

Define a container type P declaring actual types to be used for the given partner, and parameterize all entities with P. So, instead of

```
case class Company(businessContact :Person, technicalContact :Person)
```

I have

```
trait Protocol {
    type Person <: BasePerson
    ...
}

case class Company[P<:Protocol](businessContact :P#Person, technicalContact :P#Person)
```

This is better, but still every protocol would have to provide definitions of all dozens of types declared by Protocol, because scala doesn't allow overriding type declarations.

So, I tried to circumvene this limitation by introducing covariant type holder from the example above:

```
trait SubtypeOf[+T] { type Type <: T }

trait Protocol {
    type This = this.type
    val Person :SubtypeOf[BasePerson[This]] = new SubtypeOf[BasePerson[This]] { 
        type Type = BasePerson[This]
    }
    type Person = Person.Type
    ....
}

object ExtendedProtocol extends Protocol {
   override val Person = new SubtypeOf[ExtendedPerson[This]] { type Type = ExtendedPerson[This] }
}
```

This does exactly what I want: when using entities parameterized with a concrete Protocol type, all members of objects correctly show as specialized subclasses and I need to override only those few which actually change. And everything would be fine if I would limit all references from entity classes to member types declared by Protocol to direct references; any attempt to wrap a P#Person in Option[P#Person] or Seq[P#Person] leads to error from the beginning of the post.

One thing that would work from type system point of view is parameterize Protocol with all entity types, but they are far too numerous for that. I also tried the self-parameterization trick of

```
trait Protocol[P<:Protocol[P]] { this :P =>
    val Person = SubtypeOf[Person[P]]
    type Person = Person.Type
}
```

But this breaks on P#Person being a path dependent type and thus for example person.address is not type compatible with ProprietaryProtocol.Address in

```
case class Person[P<:Protocol](address :P#Address) 
val person :Person[ProprietaryProtocol]

object ProprietaryProtocol extends Protocol { ...
}
```